# MySQL insert with select on same table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

I am trying to migrate to a new database and am trying to preserve the parent child hierarchy by saving the previous ID under a 'TMP' column the problem is when I try and pull the related ID by selecting said TMP column I get the `MySQL Insert Query #1093` error. 
Here is a bit of the code to look at:

```
    INSERT INTO UnitTree (DealerID, Label, TMP) VALUES
    ((SELECT ID FROM Dealer WHERE Name='Dealer1'),'Folder1', (SELECT ID FROM  UnitTree WHERE TMP=2)),
    ((SELECT ID FROM Dealer WHERE Name='Dealer2'),'Folder2',(SELECT ID FROM UnitTree WHERE TMP=3)),
    ((SELECT ID FROM Dealer WHERE Name='Dealer3'),'Unit1',(SELECT ID FROM UnitTree WHERE TMP=4));
```

NOTE: All of the subqueries are on unique columns and will only ever return 1 result

I have looked for an answer to this and have not found an answer so I apologize if there is one. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think this is error related to locking

Comment: Try removing word "VALUES".

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with below query :

```
INSERT INTO mydata (col1, col2)
values(123,(SELECT col2 FROM (SELECT col2 FROM mydata) a));
```

Answer (score -1):

Look This :

```
SELECT ID FROM Dealer WHERE Name='Enertia'
```

this query not return id of this name in db ..